# How can I secure SQL parameters with entity framework SqlQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this method that should take an unknown amount of id's.
I got this method almost done but it isnt secure yet for obvious reasons, i know i could write my own method to strip the parameters but i would be more comfortable by using some build in method for this.

Here is the method

```
public static List<LocationModel> FetchCitiesByAreas(IEnumerable<string> areas)
    {
        using (var db = new BoligEnt())
        {
            var sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
            var first = true;

            sqlQuery.Append("SELECT DISTINCT a.city AS City, a.zip AS Zip ");
            sqlQuery.Append("FROM zip_city AS a ");
            sqlQuery.Append("WHERE country = 1 ");

            foreach (var d in areas)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    sqlQuery.Append("AND a.area_id = '" + d + "'");
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    sqlQuery.Append("OR a.area_id = '" + d + "'");
                }

            }

            return db.Database.SqlQuery<LocationModel>(sqlQuery.ToString()).ToList();
        }
    }
```

i know it have this function built in but as i stated earlier i dont know the exact amount of ids that will come in

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<LocationModel>("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @p0 ;", id).ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: what DBMS are you using? Sql Server?

Comment: Entity Framework 6 With MySql server

Comment: I think you're kinda missing the point of EF - which is: avoid having to write all the SQL, but instead use nice Linq queries to get your data that you need.....

Comment: As it is, there is a flaw in your sql.  you dont put parens around your `OR` statements, so you'd get results where country does not equal 1.

Comment: thanks didn't see that, yes i know i can use linq but this is a simplified version of an original method in the original method there is some joins and entity framework doesn't handle it as good as raw sql in this case

Comment: @MikkelRefsgaard, great question, it was fun to solve, glad you found an answer.  Looking at things, I would suggest that you head over to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and post your whole sql query.  With the `distinct` and the looping you're doing, i'd bet there'd be a way to optimize it further.  Perhaps you could whittle it down so that linq would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I completely agree with paqogomez, in that you should just use LINQ to do the query, the `.SqlQuery` has the ability to take a parameter array.  You could change your statement to look like this:

```
var sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();

sqlQuery.Append("SELECT DISTINCT a.city AS City, a.zip AS Zip ");
sqlQuery.Append("FROM zip_city AS a ");
sqlQuery.Append("WHERE country = 1 ");

for (int i = 0; i < areas.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        sqlQuery.Append("AND (a.area_id = @p" + i.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        sqlQuery.Append(" OR a.area_id = @p" + i.ToString());
    }
}
sqlQuery.Append(")");

var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<LocationModel>(sqlQuery.ToString(), areas.ToArray()).ToList();
```

I added the missing parenthesis needed to your query to correctly filter out the OR results as well. I've also taken the assumption that `areas` is something like a `List`, or at least something you can easily get the count from.

Comment: Excellent answer, I like your for loop idea. +1

Comment: Thanks man yes area is just a list<string> so it can be counted, it works great thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you just use Linq?

```
var locations = (from zip in db.zip_city
                 where areas.Contains(zip.area_id) && zip.Country == 1
                 select new LocationModel{
                   City = zip.City,
                   Zip = zip.Zip
                  })
          .Distinct()
          .ToList();
```

If you still want to parameterize your query, you need to use [`EntityCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738684(v=vs.100).aspx)

Also note that your query will fail because you havent put parenthesis around your `OR` statements.

I suggest structuring your sql like this:

```
string sqlQuery =
    @"SELECT DISTINCT a.city AS City, a.zip AS Zip
         FROM zip_city AS a 
         WHERE country = 1 AND (1=0 "

   for (int i = 0; i < areas.Count; i++)
   {
       sqlQuery.Append("OR a.area_id = @d" + i.ToString() + " ");
   }
   sqlQuery.Append(")");
```

Comment: Yes i know i can use linq this method i posted is a simplified version of the exact method. The original method have allot of joins and stuff and entity framework doesn't handle it as good as i want it to, i get a great performance boost by doing it in raw sql

Comment: Clever trick on the `for` loop to avoid the `if` statement - but shouldn't that be `1 = 0`?  `1 = 1` would evaluate to true and totally ignore all the other `OR` statements...

Comment: @entropic you are correct, `OR`'s require false to start, i use this trick mostly with `AND`'s